Какую операцию PUT или PATCH лучше использовать
Допустим есть база данных клиентов, в них хранятся поля с паспортными данными, персональной информацией, вдруг клиент решил изменить email, какой запрос лучше будет использовать с точки зрения безопасности и правильности? PUT или PATCH

С точки зрения безопасности - это протокол, по которому общаются клиент и сервер. С точки зрения описания- запрос PUT для создания данных и их обновления (принимает весь объект для изменения), PATCH для частично изменения (принимает только данные которые менять).

@noobaster скорее всего автор под безопасностью имел ввиду программную/архитектурную составляющую.
